# Pattern Lock Nokia 7.1 even thought i gave correct pass code

Tags: nokia-7.1

i am using Nokia 7.1 mobile phone. i have setup screen lock pattern and finger  print.
Now, i have problem with the phone like not able to unlock the phone eventhought i am giving correct pass code and finger print.
Now i don't know how to fix this issue in Nokia 7.1 phone, please suggest he to fix the issue. I have been restarted multiple time and i dont want to do factory reset.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Boot in safe mode. Delete all your fingerprints. Add one fingerprint. Add again the same fingerprint. If it says it is the same finger, then the reader is working https://community.phones.nokia.com/discussion/5841/fingerprint-scanner-not-working

Comment: Lock your phone. Set a temporary password to lock your screen. Unlock your phone with temporary password
https://myaccount.google.com/find-your-phone